# How to instal mysql-workbench on NixOS?

Tags: mysql-workbench, nix, workbench, nixos

I’m new on NixOS and I'm using home manager to install my applications. I was trying to install *mysql-workbench*, that’s why i added in my `home.nix` the following line:

```
home.packages = with pkgs; [
  ...
 mysql-workbench
 ];
```

After that, running home-manager switch, an error occurs during the workbench build:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/nix/store/8dmk574rg7r7xgsa47xcg7znbvz8kcyy-mysql-8.0.32/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.so', needed by 'libgdal.so.32.3.6.2'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3589: CMakeFiles/GDAL.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:136: all] Error 2
error: builder for '/nix/store/x3pq79blki1zd8jagfl5l6g7h1hl86j7-gdal-3.6.2.drv' failed with exit code 2;
       last 10 log lines:
       > [ 94%] Building CXX object gnm/gnm_frmts/db/CMakeFiles/gnm_frmts_db.dir/gnmdbnetwork.cpp.o
       > [ 94%] Built target gnm_frmts
       > [ 94%] Building CXX object gnm/gnm_frmts/file/CMakeFiles/gnm_frmts_file.dir/gnmfiledriver.cpp.o
       > [ 94%] Built target gnm
       > [ 94%] Building CXX object gnm/gnm_frmts/file/CMakeFiles/gnm_frmts_file.dir/gnmfilenetwork.cpp.o
       > [ 94%] Built target gnm_frmts_db
       > [ 94%] Built target gnm_frmts_file
       > make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/nix/store/8dmk574rg7r7xgsa47xcg7znbvz8kcyy-mysql-8.0.32/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.so', needed by 'libgdal.so.32.3.6.2'.  Stop.
       > make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3589: CMakeFiles/GDAL.dir/all] Error 2
       > make: *** [Makefile:136: all] Error 2
       For full logs, run 'nix log /nix/store/x3pq79blki1zd8jagfl5l6g7h1hl86j7-gdal-3.6.2.drv'.
error: 1 dependencies of derivation '/nix/store/cmv85cs2wslj2m3i9vgxdsgi50wn9i4d-mysql-workbench-8.0.30.drv' failed to build
error: 1 dependencies of derivation '/nix/store/fbcg07ss7pc9bc49wpxxpf6406dcqbhc-home-manager-path.drv' failed to build
error: 1 dependencies of derivation '/nix/store/grgzimdpc37yp6cyjwshhk0l5pz92g2f-home-manager-generation.drv' failed to build
```

I’m using a stable channel:

```
~ sudo nix-channel --list
home-manager https://github.com/nix-community/home-manager/archive/release-22.11.tar.gz
nixos https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-22.11
```

What could i try?
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: 
As suggested by [@Chris Stryczynski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1663462/chris-stryczynski) in the comment, I tried to use an unstable channel, but only for this package:

- first I added the unstable channel:

  ```
  ~ » sudo nix-channel --add https://nixos.org/channels/nixpkgs-unstable nixos-unstable
  ~ » sudo nix-channel --update
  ```
- then I added in my `home.nix` the following lines:

  ```
  let
    ...
    unstable = import <nixos-unstable> {};
  in
  {
    ...
    home.packages = with pkgs; [
      ...
      unstable.mysql-workbench
    ];
  }
  ```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work and these errors occur:

```
[  5%] Built target mysys_objlib
make: *** [Makefile:156: all] Error 2
error: builder for '/nix/store/lnrjks3272nl67l70l2f3cfv9m52zjla-mysql-8.0.32.drv' failed with exit code 2;
       last 10 log lines:
       > [  5%] Building CXX object mysys/CMakeFiles/mysys_objlib.dir/my_md5.cc.o
       > [  5%] Building CXX object mysys/CMakeFiles/mysys_objlib.dir/my_rnd.cc.o
       > [  5%] Building CXX object mysys/CMakeFiles/mysys_objlib.dir/my_openssl_fips.cc.o
       > [  5%] Building CXX object mysys/CMakeFiles/mysys_objlib.dir/my_aes_openssl.cc.o
       > [  5%] Building CXX object mysys/CMakeFiles/mysys_objlib.dir/build_id.cc.o
       > [  5%] Building CXX object mysys/CMakeFiles/mysys_objlib.dir/posix_timers.cc.o
       > [  5%] Building CXX object mysys/CMakeFiles/mysys_objlib.dir/my_getpwnam.cc.o
       > [  5%] Building CXX object mysys/CMakeFiles/mysys_objlib.dir/my_largepage.cc.o
       > [  5%] Built target mysys_objlib
       > make: *** [Makefile:156: all] Error 2
       For full logs, run 'nix log /nix/store/lnrjks3272nl67l70l2f3cfv9m52zjla-mysql-8.0.32.drv'.
error: 1 dependencies of derivation '/nix/store/i56gdjgdcd4nrclb9rj7cq43aii3hh4i-mysql-workbench-8.0.32.drv' failed to build
error: 1 dependencies of derivation '/nix/store/fyn6iaq0pflvmnlcwdwcmaxrrqj8nk20-home-manager-path.drv' failed to build
error: 1 dependencies of derivation '/nix/store/6rjk72ldzd0zayqg98sslidkp8hj6hwh-home-manager-generation.drv' failed to build
```

**EDIT 2**: nowadays, the solution applied in the **EDIT** works properly: I can install mysql workbench.

Comment: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/202872#issuecomment-1421057351 seems the unstable channel has this fixed

Comment: I've just added an edit trying what you suggested.